# Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassCastException:

Tags: hive, parquet

I have a Parquet file (created by Drill) that I'm trying to read in Hive as an external table.
I tried to store data from in bignit format but it's pointing to long format in parquet. While reading the data I want to read in big int format. But getting this error
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable

I tried to read data in either int or bigint format. Both of them failed with same error.